# While adding Attributes, don't want to add that field in catalog_product_flat table?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

With the help of Manage Attributes I was able to put **where condition** in Product Listing Page.

> SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`couple_band_sku`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='128' AND cat_index.is_parent=1 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (e.offer >= 1) ORDER BY `e`.`offer` DESC, `cat_index_position` asc, `cat_index`.`position` asc LIMIT 16

Now my problem is that while creating attributes suppose offer then **offer field** and **offer_value** also gets added to catalog_product_flat table.

I dont want **both** to get added in catalog_product_flat table because I am not using those fields. How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an attribute, there is a field called "Used in product listing".
Setting that to "Yes" will add the corresponding column to the flat table.
Just set it to "No".

Comment: Earlier I made i.e  Used in Product Listing and Used for Sorting in Product Listing to Yes.  I changed both to No then both field did not appear in catalog product flat table.